# Can I coalesce a column in presto DB to get a list of all possible pairs when some might be null?

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I've got a DB in Athena, imagine there is a `country`, `region` and `data` column.

I want to get a list of all unique `country`/`region` pairs, including when `region` might be blank (this is the case when the data is for the entire country).

I tried `SELECT distinct(country, region) FROM ...` but I get the error ***NOT_SUPPORTED: ROW comparison not supported for fields with null elements***

I thought this might work:

`SELECT distinct(coalesce(country,"none"), coalesce(region, "none") region) FROM ...`

but no luck either. Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (without braces):

```
SELECT DISTINCT country, region FROM ...
```